# Lattice barchart with correct spaces between columns

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I have another lattice question. Suppose I draw bar chart with this code:

```
require(lattice)
data <- data.frame(x = c(1,7,10,14,20,21), y = c(0.1,0.6,0.4,0.5,0.3,0.7))
barchart(data$y ~ data$x, horizontal = FALSE)
```

The resulting picture has a problem as bars are equally spaced, but they should not be since `x` has actually plenty of gaps between values. For example, I need 6 units of empty space between bars for x = 1 and x = 7. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + geom_bar(stat='identity', fill='lightblue') + theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, for the current project everything needs to be done in lattice. I think setting up the data differently might do the trick, namely mapping each gap point to 0. I'll try it now.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `xyplot` and specifying the panel function? This keeps the x values as numeric values rather than allowing `barchart` to convert them to factors. Using the form `panel = function(...) panel.barchart(...)` allows you to add other options to control the barchart appears.

```
require(lattice)
xyplot(y ~ x, data, panel = panel.barchart, horizontal = FALSE)
```

P.S. I suggest that you avoid the explicit `data$x` and `data$y` form and allow the function to evaluate variables in the data provided to the function. The explicit reference often leads to unanticipated results when things change.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `x` to a factor, filling in all the levels, and then plot the bar chart from the output of `xtabs`:

```
data$x <- factor(data$x, levels=1:max(data$x))
tab <- xtabs(y ~ x, data)
tab <- ifelse(tab == 0, NA, tab)  # So there aren't line segments at y=0
barchart(tab, horizontal=FALSE, xlab='x', ylab='y',
         scales=list(tck=c(1, 0)))
```